# Symfony welcome page not loading on fresh install

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I have just created a fresh Symfony project.  I initially had an SSL certificate issue where Google Chrome did not accept my certificate but I added it to my trusted certificates and now it no longer complains that it is unsafe to be on my localhost.

Now I'm having the issue of my Symfony welcome page is not loading at all.  I'm getting the following:

Symfony Serve and its failure logs:

[image]

Here is what the localhost:8000 displays:

[image]

Some additional information:

- Symfony Cli is installed
- Composer is installed
- bin/console is not installed

** Update **

I ran `symfony new my_project_name --full` as suggested and it still results like above.

[image: Result from running the full command]

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you have installed the minimal skeleton with this command:

```sh
symfony new my_project_name
```

[image: without the full template]

The above command is essentially used when you want to create something like a microservice. Here is the [document page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications) to create a new application.

If you want to create a traditional website application, you should use this command:

```sh
symfony new my_project_name --full
```

[image: with the option full]

But as you can see it, no page have been created, because Symfony is a framework and do not generate page if you do not need it (Some services that can be ceated with Symfony don't need home page)

Now, you only have to [create your first page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html#creating-a-page-route-and-controller), and you will see that it's pretty easy. Have a look to the maker-bundle too, which can help you a lot!

Comment: I ran the `symfony new my_project_name --full` and it skill does not show the welcome page for the local server. See update in the original post.

Comment: I completed answer with document links to create your first page.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely running `symfony serve` from the directory where you previously entered the `symfony new` command. There's nothing there. When `symfony new` finishes, it tells you that it created the project in a **new directory** inside your current one (see the text on the green background). You have to manually change the current directory to that (ie. `cd skills_test` according to your second image) before running `symfony serve`.